# hyperref for longtable jumps to first page of PDF

Tags: hyperref, longtable, tocloft

I have have longtable in my document, but when I click the caption name in the list of tables, or any reference to the table (using \ref{tab:table label}) it takes me to the first page of the document (rather than the 50th). Is there a solution to this

```
 \documentclass{scrreprt}
      \usepackage{booktabs}
      \usepackage{multirow}
      \usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=raggedright]{caption} 
      \usepackage{longtable, tabu}
      \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
          \hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=blue, linkcolor=black}
      \usepackage{tocloft}
          \begin{document}
          \listoftables
         \clearpage
         \footnotesize%
         \begin{center}
           \setlength\LTright{-30pt}           % default: \fill
           \begin{longtable}[l]{>{\raggedright}p{1.1cm}>{\centering}p{2cm}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}}
          \caption{table caption}\label{tab:table label}\\
          \tabuphantomline
          \hline
          Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
          \endfirsthead
          \multicolumn{3}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- Continued from previous page}} \\
          \hline
          Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ \hline
          \endhead
          \multicolumn{3}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
          \endfoot

          \endlastfoot
          1 & 2 & 3 \\
          4 & 5 & 6 \\
          7 & 8 & 9 \\
          \end{longtable}
          \end{center}
          \normalsize
          \end{document}
```

Comment: Have you run your file a couple of times?

Comment: More times than I care to remember unfortunately

Comment: One obvious error left: `\column 1` instead of `Column 1`. I get correct links for pdflatex, latex/dvips/ps2pdf, xelatex. Which driver are you using? Does the MWE generate a wrong link?

Comment: Edited now Heiko - Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Given the comments on the answer it seems that the example given here is _not_ an example of the problem "minimal" in "MWE" means minimal required _to show the problem_.

Comment: It appears to be a conflict with the arydshln package which is preventing this. Removing this solves the problem. Happy days.

Answer (score 2):

There are some errors in your MWE, but using this works just fine for me:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\newpage
\kant

\newpage
    \begin{longtable}[l]{lcr}
    \caption{table caption}\label{tab:table label}\\
    column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Just keep in mind a few things: `longtable`s are **`tables`**, not `figure`s.  They will appear in the `List of Tables`, not in the `List of Figures`.

Comment: What does the command \kant refer to or where does it come from? Also yeh I'm a clown. Of course tables appear in list of table...oops :)

Comment: `\kant` is just for creating dummy text (lipsum)

Comment: I've edited my preamble to ensure that the packages are called in the same order as your example, but clicking the title in the list of tables brings me to the first page of the document still. Any other ideas?

Comment: Write a MWE so we can help you.... otherwise we have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side I'd move also `tocloft` before `hyperref`.

Comment: Difficult Mario. What I wrote in the original is fairly representitive. Without a full example of my exact text. Basically the only difference is that I have some optional stuff in like repeating head and foot labels.
I've tried putting the label inside the caption and on its own, but still doesn't work

Comment: Done Enrico, but still no joy. Is there any conflict packages that could cause this?

Comment: @Magiclamarshmallow Maybe there are some packages that you are loading that are causing this problem, that's why you need to write a MWE that actually shows the issue.  Your code ---as I have written it in my answer--- works just fine.

Comment: @MarioS.E. I've edited the original post to be a more complete example. I've not called some packages like geometry, xcolor, booktabs and many more. I can provide a list of these if you need them, but it's hardly a minimal example if I do.  Is there a shortcut that one can use like phantom section or something?

Comment: Stay away from `tabu`... it is a package that the author himself has insisted he is going to completely modify (I think he already has) and is not compatible with many other that have been around for a long time.  You also need to comment `\tabuphantomline`

Comment: @MarioS.E. If I delete \tabuphantomline and replace it with a row of & & & \\ will that suffice?

Comment: @Magiclamarshmallow trial and error, your best friend :)

Comment: I've still not got the hyperref to work though....

I think I'll have to do it from the preamble with something like \captionsetup[longtable]{belowskip=1em}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15318/discussion-between-magiclamarshmallow-and-mario-s-e).

Comment: It appears to be a conflict with the arydshln package which is preventing this. Removing this solves the problem. Happy days. Cheers all!